# creating new pandas column based on existing columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have pandas data frame `df` of agents calling data with two timestamp columns as `start_time`, and `end_time`, and a blank column as `availability` which has `Nan`. Dataframe was given as:

```
  start_time                 end_time         Availability    
                       
2023-02-07 08:00:11     2023-02-07 08:01:49    NaN   
2023-02-07 08:00:24     2023-02-07 08:02:05    NaN  
2023-02-07 08:01:56     2023-02-07 08:06:28    NaN 
2023-02-07 08:01:42     2023-02-07 08:03:56    NaN
2023-02-07 08:02:03     2023-02-07 08:07:18    NaN  
2023-02-07 08:02:12     2023-02-07 08:03:45    NaN 
2023-02-07 08:03:54     2023-02-07 08:06:21    NaN
2023-02-07 08:04:54     2023-02-07 08:06:08    NaN
```

Now, I want to update column `availability` based on the comparison between `start_time` and `end_time` such that comparison will start from `df['end_time'][0:last_index]` with `df['start_time'][1:last_index]`. If `start_time` is greater than `end_time` that means the agent is available for the following call and `availability` will be marked as `Yes` else it will be marked as `No`.

For example, the first comparison will be between the first `end_time` value `2023-02-07 08:01:49`  with `start_time` values i.e `2023-02-07 08:00:24` and then `2023-02-07 08:01:56` which is greater than `end_time` so `availability` marked as `Yes` and no further comparison will be checked afterward, So data frame after first iteration will be,

```
  start_time                 end_time         Availability    
                       
2023-02-07 08:00:11     2023-02-07 08:01:49    NaN   
2023-02-07 08:00:24     2023-02-07 08:02:05    No  
2023-02-07 08:01:56     2023-02-07 08:06:28    Yes 
2023-02-07 08:01:42     2023-02-07 08:03:56    NaN
2023-02-07 08:02:03     2023-02-07 08:07:18    NaN  
2023-02-07 08:02:12     2023-02-07 08:03:45    NaN 
2023-02-07 08:03:54     2023-02-07 08:06:21    NaN
2023-02-07 08:04:54     2023-02-07 08:06:08    NaN
```

Now for the second iteration, records where `availability` is `Yes` would not be included in comparison only `No` and `Nan` will be considered. So, the second comparison will be between the second `end_time` value i.e. `2023-02-07 08:02:05` with the `start_time` value i.e `2023-02-07 08:00:24`, **not 2023-02-07 08:01:56** then `2023-02-07 08:01:42` then `2023-02-07 08:02:03` then `2023-02-07 08:02:12` which is greater than `end_time` so `availability` marked as `Yes` and no further comparison will be checked afterward, So data frame after second iteration will be,

```
  start_time                 end_time         Availability    
                       
2023-02-07 08:00:11     2023-02-07 08:01:49    NaN   
2023-02-07 08:00:24     2023-02-07 08:02:05    No  
2023-02-07 08:01:56     2023-02-07 08:06:28    Yes 
2023-02-07 08:01:42     2023-02-07 08:03:56    No
2023-02-07 08:02:03     2023-02-07 08:07:18    No 
2023-02-07 08:02:12     2023-02-07 08:03:45    Yes 
2023-02-07 08:03:54     2023-02-07 08:06:21    NaN
2023-02-07 08:04:54     2023-02-07 08:06:08    NaN
```

and this is how I can check for agents available for calls. I appreciate any help to be in Pandas.

Thanks in advance!!!!